# Adonisjs and Nextjs implementation

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, next.js, adonis.js

I need some help implementing nextjs with adonisjs. There is a package doing the exact same thing for Nuxtjs(Adonuxt). If anyone has implemented this stack of technologies any help or guidelines would be gladly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

check this **package** :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/adonis-nextjs

I explained everything you can do to run `nextjs` app with `adonis js`